# Binary vs Multiclass Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Consider an image dataset that has two types of things: cars and airplanes. Let $A$ be a binary classifier trained to classify an image as having a car or airplane.

Suppose we now have four refined subcategories, for example car:sedan, car:truck, airplane:cessna, airplane:airbus. We can train a similar *multiclass*-classifier B to categorize each image into one of these subcategories.

Lets assume we have the same backbone (say, ResNet) for both networks, and everything is equal, except for the binary vs softmax outputs at the end.

> Question: When it comes to distinguishing cars from airplanes, which
>   classifier would perform better?

To be clear, classifier $B$ has a softmax output, so for $B$ we can proxy for the general "car" class by looking at $P(car):=P(car:sedan)+P(car:truck)$.

Intuitively, I'm leaning toward $B$ doing slightly better, but only because (all other things equal), $B$ has two neurons acting on the FC layer just above, compared to the binary classifier which has one. Then again, $A$ was trained directly on the objective of car vs airplane.

However, I'm much more interesting in understanding if $B$ is fundamentally more *efficient* at learning than $A$. We're teaching $B$ to be able to distinguish within each class, although the overall objective of car vs. plane doesn't require this.

References to literature on this would be highly appreciated!